# Jmeter testing integration with IBM dtapower

Tags: ssl, jmeter, ssl-certificate, performance-testing, ibm-datapower

Need your help in setting the SSL manager in Jmeter for performance testing with IBM datapower.

I tried the below steps to Add cert.

•   Added (* .jks /*.p12 ) file in the jmeter GUI > Options > SSL Manager. 
•   I tried the setting the jks file in system.properties file too.

Path : *\jMETER\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\system.properties

```
# Truststore properties (trusted certificates)
#javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/[jsse]cacerts
#javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
#javax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider
#javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType [default = KeyStore.getDefaultType()]

# Keystore properties (client certificates)
# Location
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=****.jks -- Added
#
#The password to your keystore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=****-- Added
#
#javax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider
#javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType [default = KeyStore.getDefaultType()]
```

I dont see the SSL handshake jMETER and datapower even after i followed ablove steps. Getting below error from datapower.

```
12:47:26 AM        ssl            error      51751363                            10.123.98.73        0x806000ca          valcred (###_CVC_Reverse_Server): SSL Proxy Profile '###_SSLPP_Reverse_Server': connection error: peer did not send a certificate
12:47:26 AM        mpgw     error      51751363                            10.123.98.73        0x80e00161         source-https (###_HTTPS_FSH_CON_****): Request processing failed: Connection terminated before request headers read because of the connection error occurs, from URL: 10.123.98.73:58394
12:47:26 AM        ssl            error      51751363                            10.123.98.73        0x8120002f          sslproxy (####_SSLPP_Reverse_Server): SSL library error: error:140890C7:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:peer did not
```

Can you please advice how to send the cert(.jks/ .p12) file from jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change "Implementation" of your HTTP Request sampler(s) to Java. The fastest and the easiest way of doing this is using [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults).
2. If you're using .p12 keystores you will need an extra line in the *system.properties* file like:

   ```
   javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12
   ```
3. JMeter restart is required to pick the properties up.

See [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates) article for more information.

Comment: Hi Dmitri,Thanks for your Input.We have tried all the options . We are using the Websocket Sampler in meter, it works for WS not for WSS. Jmeter is not able to pick the KeyStore only for WSS.